# How do I display this collection?

Tags: javascript, meteor, user-profile

I am trying to make profile page and, I need to display the profilename and bio to a template. The problem is I can't get the Id of each profile object. If I can get the Id of each profile like how it's done in the [book](http://book.discovermeteor.com/) with postId. [Here](https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/blob/master/collections/posts.js) The code below is the way I thought it would work but did not. If you tell me how to get the Id that would be great thanks.

```
Profile = new Meteor.Collection('profile');

Profile.allow({
    update: ownsDocument
})

Profile.deny({
  update: function(profileId, profile, fieldNames) {
    return (_.without(fieldNames, 'bio').length > 0);
  }
});


Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
    Meteor.methods({
        profile: function(postAttributes) {
    var user = Meteor.user();
    var profile = _.extend(_.pick(options.profile, 'bio'), {
        userId: user._id, 
        profilename: user.username, 
        submitted: new Date().getTime(),
        postsCount: 0, posts : []
    });


    var profileId = Profile.insert(profile);

    return profileId;
    }

   });
    return user;
});
```

Comment: Could you possibly add some indentation to your source code example? It's hardly readable without it. Also, why are you defining the `post` method inside `onCreateUser` callback? I believe it should be done in the global context.

Comment: Ok Thanks I will try that and fix the typo right now that is profile in my code just looked I must have typed it wrong

Comment: I need to create a profile for each user when a new account is made.

Comment: Understood, but that's not what `Meteor.methods` is designed for.

Comment: Ok this is just one of the way I have tried this most have not included Meteor.methods any help is good i am very new to the meteor. How would you create this in theory. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem a little confused on some Meteor ideas.

Firstly Meteor.methods({ ... }) are functions that can be called client side using Meteor.call({ })

They should appear at the top level and not inside other functions like Accounts.onCreateUser

For this use case I don't see why you need a method at all though. All you want to do is retrieve data that you will be storing in data that is going to be sent to the client anyway.

If you use the accounts-base package then you automatically get a Meteor.users collection that would be fine for what you want to do. I don't see the need for a Profile collection

Here's a meteorpad illustrating it: http://meteorpad.com/pad/xL9C8eMpcwGs553YD

Note I store the bio in the profile section of the user. This is because a user can edit their own profile section by default and so I can do Meteor.users.update( ... ) client side.

This is just an example to show some of the concepts. It does have bad practice in it. For a start I would recommend adding the package accounts-ui and using the {{> loginButtons}} helper. It gives you the error checking and so on. The reason I didn't use it was because I wanted to show how to allow a user to enter their bio prior to creating the account and how you can use that in Accounts.onCreateUser.

Comment: The only thing I can't get is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305254/what-is-wrong-with-this-route-to-user-profile)

Answer (score 1):

In the discover meteor example, they are using a method to insert a `Post` and then return its id. In your case, a new `Profile` is being inserted inside of an asynchronous callback so there's no way for you to return the id. However, you know the `userId`, so you can use that to get the profile.

**Server**

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){

    var user = Meteor.user();
    var profile = _.extend(_.pick(options.profile, 'bio'), {
        userId: user._id, 
        profilename: user.username, 
        submitted: new Date().getTime(),
        postsCount: 0,
        posts : []
    });

    Profile.insert(profile);

    return user;
});
```

**Client**

```
Template.profile.profile = function () {
  return Profiles.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()});
};
```