# what is wrong with this route to user_profile?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, iron-router

I am trying to add a profile page to the microscope app. Thanks to help I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215609/how-do-i-display-this-collection) I was able to get most of it working but I can't get the route to another users profile to work. This is the code for the route. Thanks

in comment.html template

```
<span class="author"><a href="{{pathFor 'user_profile'}}">{{username}}</a></span>
```

router.js

```
this.route('user_profile',{
    path: '/profile/:_username',
    waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('userprofile', this.params._username)
  },
    data: function () {return user.findOne(this.params._username)}
});
```

publications.js

```
Meteor.publish('userprofile', function (username) {
   return user.find(username);
});
```

profile.js

```
Template.user_profile.helpers({
  username: function() {
      return this.user().username;
  },
  bio: function() {
      return this.user().profile.bio;
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the `user` collection? The default Meteor user collection is `Meteor.users`.

Comment: It is the default with accounts_base and accounts_password I think. I am very new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Meteor user collection used by accounts-base and accounts-password is `Meteor.users`, not `user`. Also, `collection.find(x)` will find a document whose `_id` is `x`; if you want to find documents whose `username` is `x`, you need `collection.find({username: x})`.

```js
this.route('user_profile',{
  path: '/profile/:username',
  waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('userprofile', this.params.username)
  },
  data: function () {return Meteor.users.findOne({username: this.params.username})}
});
```

I renamed the `_username` parameter to `username`, that way the `pathFor` helper will be able to automatically fill it in. I also replaced `user` with `Meteor.users` and passed in the correct selector.

```js
Meteor.publish('userprofile', function (username) {
  return Meteor.users.find(
    {username: username},
    {fields: {username: 1, profile: 1}}
  );
});
```

I replaced `user` with `Meteor.users` and fixed the selector again, and I limited which fields we publish (since the user document contains sensitive data like login tokens, you don't want to publish the whole thing).

```
Template.user_profile.helpers({
  username: function() {
    return this.username;
  },
  bio: function() {
    return this.profile.bio;
  }
});
```

Inside the `user_profile` template, the data context (which you specified in the `data` parameter in the route) is a user document, so `this` is already a user document. Note that these helpers are redundant (you can get the username with `{{username}}` and the bio with `{{profile.bio}}` even without these helpers).

Comment: How do I add to more feilds in profile to get published.